# setting auto return in paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been searching on enabling auto return/redirect after successful payment for paypal sandbox but i just couldn't find the button for it.

Note: I found the auto redirect in paypal standard account but and enable it but it seems that it will not affect paypal sandbox.

Where to configure auto return/redirect in paypal sandbox?

Comment: http://www.techycommerce.com/auto-return-does-not-work/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that your customers are redirected automatically,you should also activate the “AutoReturn” feature in your PayPal Account.

Login to your PayPal account(www.sandbox.paypal.com)
click on Profile
click ‘My selling preferences
click on Update next to Website preferences
set Auto Return to On
enter a valid URL in the Return URL text box
scroll to the bottom of the page and click “Save”

After you have activated this feature, your customers will be redirected automatically to your side and they don’t need to click on the Button.

Please note, if they are using the paypal account optional feature to pay with a credit card, we are not allowed to redirect automatically and they will need to click the return to merchant Button.

Please be informed that Automatic return URL will work only when the purchases are made with PayPal account.

If Purchases are made via Credit card, buyers will need to manually click on the return URL to get back to the specified return URL.

**P.S** This applies for Sandbox too.

[image]

Comment: i will try it and give feedback

Comment: I would be glad if someone can give screenshot of where to find the autocomplete option in sandbox.
I follow the same step in both sandbox and normal paypal account.

Normal paypal: My account -> profile -> my selling tools -> website preferences -> auto return -> on
Sandbox paypal: My account -> profile -> end case (seems like a lot of option is missing here, can't find my selling tools)

Comment: Is your sandbox email address, a business account?

the direct link is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Comment: how to check if the sandbox email address is a business account? i created the sandbox account with email and inside it have a business and personal account by default

Comment: check the updated answer with screenshot, its is recommended to create sandbox accounts from developer.paypal.com

Comment: is a business account

Comment: can you provide screen shot of this page?
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

Comment: weird... now i cannot login sandbox paypal even after i clear all the cache

Comment: yes my account was previously created on developer and i have tried the direct link given before but it shows that the page does not exist

Comment: you seem to have so many problems, raise a ticket at www.paypal.com/mts